# How to use the allowsEditing

Tags: ios, camera, photo

I just want the user to take a photo in app→crop→save. So I would want to use the allowsEditing property of UIImagePickerControl. However I don't know how i can do it.  this is my code until now for camera.

```
-(IBAction)TakePhoto {
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for pick photo from camera

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];   
}
```

use this for pick photo from photo library

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

use following two delegate methods

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Add this in your ViewDidLoad method, so if your device is not support camera then display this alert message.

```
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                    delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [myAlertView show];

}
```

Add both protocols to the AppViewController.h file:

```
@interface APPViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xm4w2b&s=5 I have so many errors.. I can't find what is wrong..

Comment: one } is not completed after the ViewDidLoad method

Comment: the image cropper gets stuck in the middle, any fixes?